# IBM Rational Doors : all changes are lost in module after closing

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational

That is, after adding new columns and objects to a module and closing/saving these changes, I manually reopen the module and the columns are gone, although the objects remain in their appropriate places. can anybody tell me how to solve this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the View, not just the Module.

The following Procedure is taken from IBM's [Help Page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/doorshlp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/t_createviews.html)

> **Procedure:**
>
> 1. In the module window, click View > Save As.
> 2. On the General tab, type the name. To overwrite an existing view,
>      type the name of the view you want to overwrite. Note: View names
>      are case sensitive. To overwrite an existing view, you must type the
>      name exactly as it appears in the Views list.
> 3. Optional: Enter additional information about the view in the
>      Description box.
> 4. Optional: Select or clear the Remember Settings for options.
> 5. Optional: Select a Default option for the view. The default view is
>      the view that is displayed when the module is opened. If you do not make it a default view, it is listed in the views list and can be
>      selected when the module is open.
> 6. Use the Access to this view section to define whether the view is
>      private or public.
> 7. Optional: Set additional rules for the view on the Advanced tab.